# BlackArch failed to boot after updating systemd

Tags: arch-linux, boot, boot-loader

I updated systemd and linux-firmware after restarting I get the error:

```
   :: running early hook [udev]
systemd-tempfiles : error while loading shared libraries : libcryptsetup.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directorty
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: error while loading shared libraries: libcryptsetup.so.12: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
:: running hook [udev]
:: Triggering uevents...
udevadm: error while loading shared libraries: libcryptsetup.so.12: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory 
udevadm: error while loading shared libraries: libcryptsetup.so.12: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory 
udevadm: error while loading shared libraries: libcryptsetup.so.12: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
:: running hook [keymap]
:: Loading keymap...done.
:: running hook [encrypt]
Waiting 10 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/8abcac1e-3502-****-***-*********** ...
waiting 10 seconds foe device /dev/mapper/root ...
ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/root/' not found. Skipping fsck.
:: Mounting '/dev/mapper/r00t' on real root
mount: /new_root: no filesystem type specified
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs ]#
```

and the output is :

```
[ blackarch / ]# ldd /usr/lib/libcryptsetup.so.12
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc0d35000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /usr/lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f6731f6d000)
        libdevmapper.so.1.02 => /usr/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02 (0x00007f6731d17000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f67319fb000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f67317e6000)
        libjson-c.so.2 => /usr/lib/libjson-c.so.2 (0x00007f67315db000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f67313bd000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6731005000)
        /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f67323c5000)
        libudev.so.1 => /usr/lib/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f6730de7000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6730a9b000)
[ blackarch / ]#
```

Current Versions are:

```
systemd 235.38-4
systemd-sysvcompat 235.38-4
Cryptsetup 2.0.0-1
linux 4.14.5-1
linux-firmware 20171206.fdee922-1
```

But When I am using cryptsetup from live usb it's mounting my root file system `/dev/sda3`.

Any solution how can I fix this?

Comment: Please boot with liveCD, `chroot /mnt` (assuming `/dev/sda3` is mounted on `/mnt` ) and issue `ldd /usr/lib/libcryptsetup.so.12` and check if all the dep's are there; add the output to the question. Note that I do not know where `libcryptsetup.so.12` lives on your system so you might have to adapt the path.

Comment: @thecarpy ldd /usr/lib/libcryptsetup.so.12 giving error like No such file or Directory found but ldd /usr/lib/libcryptsetup.so giving some output of files.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one coming, you need to find the `so`, try `ldd $(find /usr -name libcryptsetup.so.12)`

Comment: @thecarpy I tried "find /usr -name libcryptsetup.so.12" and it was in "/usr/lib/libcryptsetup.so.12"

Comment: Issue ldd /usr/lib/libcryptsetup.so.12 and check if all the dep's are there; add the output to the question.

Comment: @thecarpy yes sir added the output in question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know BlackArch but it seems that the two packages in question come from the main archlinux repos.

You should never update single packages. Now you have systemd which is linked to the new version of [crypt](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/cryptsetup/) (released yesterday), but you don't have this version of crypt.

You have to start a livecd and do a full system upgrade. You can use [arch-chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root#Using_arch-chroot). The [blackarch faq](https://blackarch.org/faq.html) says, you should run this command:

```
pacman -Syyu --needed --force blackarch
```

Comment: Sir I upgraded full system using Live USB but problem is still as It was. :/

Comment: systemd,libsystemd,cryptsetup,Linux everything updated successfully but still showing the error.

Comment: Add the versions of this packages and the mirror you use to the question.

Comment: yes sir added the package versions.I used "pacman --root=/mnt -Syyu --force --needed blackarch" using Live usb after opening r00t sda3 in and mount in /mnt.I think it is used global Mirror as I used Live usb.

Comment: I recommend you to use archlinux. You wouldn't experience such problems and we could help you better.